# Start server from within existing Vim instance

Tags: clientserver

Is it possible to have an existing vim instance launch a server from within, without using the `--servername` command-line option? (I would want to do this from a `FileType` autocommand).

Alternatively, is there any inconvenient in setting up a shell `alias vim='vim --servername $$'` (or any other unique identifier), so that *any* `vim` instance is its own server? (Then when I need to contact a specific one, I can always patch something up out of `--serverlist` and `--remote-cmd`).

Comment: AFAIK any Vim instance *is* already its own server, and its instance name can be found by reading the `v:servername` variable. See also `:h clientserver` (the "SERVER NAME" section).

Comment: I just tried this and it works for `gvim` but not for terminal-bound `vim`, which is my use case. (Although client-server still works with these). However, your answer suggests that no, there is no counter-indication to *always* having a server on.

Comment: So all is good :)